# SwiftUI List Data can't update when data changes from notification

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to trigger swiftUI List UI update when the notification reached with data changing. Here is my code:

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
     @Published var contracts: [String] = ["Good"]

     init(contracts: [String]) {
        self.contracts = contracts
     }

     func updateContracts() {
        self.contracts.append("good")
     }

}


struct MyView: View {

    @ObservedObject var myModel = MyModel(contracts: ["Good", "Morning"])

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(myModel.contracts, id: \.self) { data in
                Text(data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The notification part in another place is:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(modelsUpdated), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: kxxxxUpdate), object: nil)

 @objc func modelsUpdated(notification: Notification) {
     MyView().myModel.updateContracts()
}
```

If I moved this notification part inside the `MyModel` class, then call
`updateContracts()` directly in `modelsUpdated` the UI was updated.

The code is:

```
    class MyModel: ObservableObject {
           
         @Published var contracts: [String] = ["G
    
    ood"]
        

         init(contracts: [String]) {
               self.contracts = contracts
               NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(modelsUpdated), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: kxxxxUpdate), object: nil)
            
         }

         func updateContracts() {
            self.contracts.append("good")
         }

         @objc func modelsUpdated(notification: Notification) {
              updateContracts() // works
         }
    
    }
```

Anyone knows why? thanks!

**EDIT**

`MyView()` above is just for telling is an instance of `MyView`, it's the one on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you call
MyView().myModel.updateContracts()
You create new instance of your view, which is not the same one you are displaying.